# How to add java array data to PostgreSQL query

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, arraylist

I'm using java spring boot to connect(jpaRepository) to Postgres DB .

I'm getting GET input parameters in array as below

`localhost:1111/abc/V1/XYZ?item1&place=1,2,3&location=345`

I'm trying below query to fetch the details from Postgres

```
select * 
from Tablename 
where item=1 
AND place=(how to insert 1,2,3 in array/list so I can fetch the details )
```

Comment: create a method in your Repository that extends JPARepository like: `findAllByItemAndPlaceIn(int itemId, List<Integer> place)`

Comment: Are you going to use prepareStatement? I don't know but, does JPA doesn't provide any method with List? Actually, you may use "IN" clause like "place in (1,2,3)"

Comment: Hi @SandeepPoonia thanks for your reply ,but my data type for place is integer in postgre ,so arm getting error like explicit type casts needed !.Now how to figure out this ,Please guide me with snipped/sample code

Comment: The method that I mentioned, is already expecting the place value as Integer, so unless you are not passing it as an integer, or  have a different type in DB, you should be okay with this method

Comment: Hi @SandeepPoonia am using below query as  

 @Query(value="select *FROM\"ABC\".\"XYZ\"where item=?1"+AND place=?2",nativeQuery=true)
Optional<entityclass> findAllByItemAndPlaceIn(Interger itemId,List<Interger> place)

And facing error :operation does not exist :integer=record
Hint:no operation matches the given name and argument types.you might need to add explicit type cast